# Verilog, How to pass different parameters when I use generate to instantiation module?

Tags: parameter-passing, verilog, generate

I have a question about parameters passing. I used generate for to do module instantiation. But how to pass different parameters to each module?
For example:

```
generate
   for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin:ModIns
       Mod #(.p1(?),.p2(?)) M (
       // Signal connection
       );
   end
endgenerate
```

For N modules, each with different p1 and p2. How to do that? By the way, the number of parameters is very large, can I pass parameters as a file?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents.
Declare a 2-D register and store all the parameters there.

```
reg [31:0] param_mem1 [N-1:0]; //Assuming parameter size to be 32 bit wide
reg [31:0] param_mem2 [N-1:0];

always@(posedge clk)
begin
 for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
 begin
   param_mem1[i] <= i; //Here replace 'i' with your actual parameter value
   param_mem2[i] <= i+1; //Dummy assignment, please use intended values
 end
end

generate
 for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin:ModIns
   Mod #(.p1(param_mem1[i]),.p2(param_mem2[i])) M (
   // Signal connection
   );
end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 0):

First: No you can't read it from a file. Parameters have to be known at compile time and a file is only readable in run time.

You can derive them from a genvar or pass them through a hierarchy, but then it more or less stops. Maybe what you are trying to do can be solved in a different way but the scope of the problem you have outlined for us here is rater limited.

As always: *Tell us your problem, not your solution.*

Comment: Actually, I need to build many hundreds even thousands of modules only with different parameters like length, width, weight, etc. I don't want to put them as input because there are gonna be too many. Is there a better way?

Comment: No, what you are talking about sounds like a library. You could make a Perl or C program to generate the source code. That is what is normally used to generate libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do this in SystemVerilog because a parameter can be an array, and your generate loop could select an element for each iteration of the loop.
In Verilog, you can pack your elements into a bit-vector, and your generate loop could select a slice for each iteration of the loop.

```
parameter A1={8'd1, 8'd2, 8'd3, 8'd4, ...};
parameter A2={8'd9, 8'd8, 8'd7, 8'd6, ...};
generate
   for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin:ModIns
       Mod #(.p1(A1[i*8+:8),.p2(A2[i*8+:8])) M (
       // Signal connection
       );
   end
endgenerate
```

If you want to define the parameters from a file, you can put the parameter declarations in a separate file and  `` `include `` the file.

Comment: In the Verilog, I can't do bit select to parameter. If I pack them into a bit vector, Do I need to treat them as inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This compiles with VCS:

```
genvar port_idx;
generate
for (port_idx = 0; port_idx < 5; port_idx++) begin : intf
    xactor_t xactor (core_clk, core_rst);
    defparam xactor.intf_id = 18 + port_idx;
end
```